# Can't stroke path, have done everything the online tutorials say (and trust me, I have looked at all of them)

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, gimp, stroke

I made a path with the pen tool. I tried selecting and deselecting it. I made sure the visibility was on. I edit stroked and right click stroked. I closed and restarted gimp. It worked before, and now it doesn't work. I am super frustrated. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this question could be improved if you mentioned it was about gimp (I see that it's tagged, but mentioning it in the question would be useful).  Also, describing what happens when you say "it doesn't work" would be useful.  Does the selection change?  Does anything happen at all?  Is there anything in the action buffer?  etc etc.

Comment: I wrote an answer over at http://superuser.com/questions/356380/how-do-i-stroke-a-path-in-gimp-or-just-draw-a-line/645080#645080 that you might want to look at.  I had the same problem, and finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt uninstalling, deleting any remaining config files, and reinstalling. If it used to work, something was changed since then and reintalling may revert whatever was modified back to it's original state.

Comment: Note that "something was changed" could also be the user is not interacting with the product the same way they did before . . . e.g. different file, different order of operations, different layers, etc.

Comment: This is true, but I gave the asker the benefit of the doubt. From the original post, they seem to have retraced their steps (or maybe that's just my assumption).

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the comments. Ernie, I am pretty sure I am doing the same thing. For example, if I open a new file and do exactly the same thing, i.e. draw an ellipse, select to path, edit stroke path using brush tools emulate dynamics, it works fine. Try to do the same thing on my document, and nothing. Also, nothing happens when I try to stroke a pen tool path, using the same steps. I have also tried right-clicking the path in the path tab menu and going to stroke path that way. Filoxo, I have uninstalled and deleted my config files and then installed again. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Hi guys, also: can I somehow upload the file to this forum, so you can mess around with the file and see what I'm talking about, and maybe it would be easier to discover a solution with the actual thing in front of you? Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris so it works if you do it with a new document, but doesn't work if you open and try to edit a file?  I don't know GIMP well, but that sounds like a critical difference.  When you open the file, does GIMP open it in it's native format, or does it keep it in the on-disk format?

Comment: @Chris, upload your file to a cloud service (Dropbox, Google Drive, Box, etc.) and post a link. I am pretty familiar with GIMP and I'd be more than willing to take a look at the file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess the problem is resolved. I'm still curious what the problem was, but what I did was just delete all the layers but the top layer and then export it into png and then open it in a new doc. That resolved the problem. Since I deleted the old file, I can't upload it. I would have been interested to see if anyone could figure out what was wrong, though.